# Print .NET WF4 workflow from rehosted designer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, workflow-foundation-4

I want to print the nice workflow rendering from the rehosted workflow designer of .NET 4.5. The standard technique to print WPF controls does not work - one can see the surroundings of the workflow designer itself, but the workflow rendering stays blank.

I take the workflow definition from another Workflow Designer in the following example, but I need to be able to print from a XAML string too (so it would not work to just rely on the displayed Workflow Designer - I need an independent one).

I tried the following code:

```
public void Print()
{
    var printDlg = new PrintDialog();

    if (printDlg.ShowDialog() != true) return;

    _workflowDesigner.Flush();

    var wd = new WorkflowDesigner();

    DynamicActivity rootActivity;

    using (var sr = new StringReader(_workflowDesigner.Text))
    {
        rootActivity = (DynamicActivity)ActivityXamlServices.Load(sr);
    }

    // wrap the activity in an ActivityBuilder because the designer expects it this way
    var ab = new ActivityBuilder
    {
        Implementation = rootActivity.Implementation?.Invoke(),
        Name = rootActivity.Name
    };

    wd.Load(ab);

    var grid = new Grid();
    grid.Children.Add(wd.View);

    printDlg.PrintVisual(grid, "My Workflow");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the designer actually render the activity. See [this MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/flow/2011/08/16/how-to-save-wf4-workflow-definition-to-image-using-code/) for details on the whys and hows. The blog entry is about saving as an image but the same concept applies.  Render it first and then print it.

Comment: Thank you; I hoped there was another way instead of relying on the timer, but it seems I have to go down that route.